# Operation is not supported for read-only collection android studio update last version

Tags: android-studio

I updated to Android Studio and for any project I have this message when compiling :

`Operation is not supported for read-only collection`

I tried :

- invalid cache / restart
- create new projet in same/other default folder
- reinstall from scratch android studio
- uncheck Experimental settings
- restore default settings